# Scheduling timed service

Tags: android, calendar, job-scheduling

how i can write a reminder for a list with a checkbox that repeat every day?
i know i write this wrong but i cant fix it please help

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
            editor.putBoolean("CheckValue"+position, isChecked);
            editor.apply();
            if (isChecked) {

                Calendar updateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                updateTime.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5:00"));
                updateTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
                updateTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 40);
                if(System.currentTimeMillis() <= updateTime.getTimeInMillis()){
                    constractJob();

                }
```

amd this is constractJob

```
private void constractJob(){
    JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(JOBID,new ComponentName(context, MyService.class));
    builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED)

            .setPersisted(true);
    mJobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
}
```

and this is my service the tatarka is working on api lower then lollipop

```
public class MyService extends me.tatarka.support.job.JobService {


@Override
public boolean onStartJob(me.tatarka.support.job.JobParameters params) {
    PugNotification.with(this).load()
            .title("title")
            .message("message")
            .bigTextStyle("bigi")
            .smallIcon(R.drawable.pugnotification_ic_launcher)
            .largeIcon(R.drawable.pugnotification_ic_launcher)
            .flags(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .simple()
            .build();

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(me.tatarka.support.job.JobParameters params) {
    return true;
}
```

sorry for bad english

Comment: your question is unclear. you do not provide the exact error you are getting/research done/problem you are facing.

Comment: its not working i want to know how i can write a reminder for a list with a checkbox that repeat every day